# Adjust width of UITableView based on UITableViewCell with longest width

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that serves as a pop up menu and I want to set its width to the width of its widest `UITableViewCell`. However, I've tried obtaining the width of the cell `UILabel` / `contentView` and it always returns 0. I try doing this after I've added to the subview and after the table has been reloaded and still the same result. I've done it within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and outside of it and same result. Is it possible to do this? My code is listed below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (tableViewCell == nil) 
    {
        tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [[tableViewCell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 17]];
    [[tableViewCell textLabel] setText: [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:0]];
    [[tableViewCell imageView] setImage: [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:1]];

    if (tableViewCell.textLabel.frame.size.width > tableView.frame.size.width)
    {
        CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;
        tableViewFrame.size.width = tableViewCell.textLabel.frame.size.width;
        tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

UPDATE: Just to clarify, I'm not interested in changing the width of the TableViewCell while the TableView is reloading. I'd be fine with loading the table, then calculating the appropriate max width, then reloading it again with the new appropriate width.

Comment: For some reason I don't think a UITableViewCell's textLabel can stretch beyond the bounds of the cell. The cell's content view will scale the textLabel based on the width of the cell.  I don't think you can alter the frame of the textLabel, either.  You should try implementing a custom cell with your own label subview.

Comment: I don't want to stretch the UITableViewCell, I want to figure out the width of the widest UITableCell, and then readjust the table accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this may be from another angle.  The textLabel won't expand based on the text it contains.

You should loop through the self.menuItems array and call the function that can be applied to an NSString.

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font;
```

e.g.

```
width = [menuItem sizeWithFont:font].width;
```

Keep tabs of the widest width in the array and set your tableview to be that width.  The font is whatever font your cell is drawing it's label in.

Comment: Thanks this is a good work around, but just to address what you said initially, I'm not trying to expand the textLabel, just trying to figure out the width of the largest label, then readjust the tableView accordingly.

Comment: The textLabels will all be the same width unless you've manually changed them elsewhere.